# Class objects inheritance / covariance

Tags: scala, covariance

I need to be able to compare Class objects relatively to the hierarchy of their parent types.

I want some method to compare `Class[A]` and `Class[B]`.
I need some kind of method that takes class objects and would return true when `A extends B`

Obviously I can't use `isInstanceOf` because Class is not covariant.

`Class[A].isInstanceOf[Class[B]]` returns false. What would return true in that case?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try [`Class.isAssignableFrom(Class)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#isAssignableFrom%28java.lang.Class%29):

```
classOf[A] isAssignableFrom classOf[B]
```

Comment: Ah well, that works. Thanks :) Somehow I had the impression isAssignableFrom was exactly the same as isInstanceOf, but it's not, it works on class objects, just what I need. Thanks!